# What are the characters that has their own unique abilities throughout the DB series?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

There are quite a few characters that has their own unique abilities throughout the whole Dragon Ball series. Some of them are mostly forgotten due to their last appearance was on the original Dragon Ball.

Here's some example I can think of at the moment:

1. Fortuneteller Baba's employees (except [Bandages the Mummy](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Bandages_the_Mummy) and [Grandpa Gohan](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Grandpa_Gohan))
2. Ginyu - [Body Change](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Body_Change)
3. Guldo - [Time Freeze](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Freeze), temporarily stop time
4. Majin Buu - [Change Beam / Chocolate Beam](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Chocolate_Beam), change any object or person into sweets.
5. Ebifurya - [Freezing Fist](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Freezing_Fist), freezes the victims.

Answer (score 3):

I would also add:

6. General Blue - psychic abilities
7. Giran - Merry-Go-Round Gum (although it's stated that members of his race can use it)
8. Man-Wolf - turns into human during fullmoon

There are also other characters like Chiaotzu who can use telekinesis, but I'm sure there were some other characters that could do that as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dabura - turn people into stone with spit
Hit - Tokitobashi (jumping backwards fractions of seconds in time) . 
      Making ki clones
      Hiding in another dimension
Wiss - Turn back time
That fish fighter from the afterworld who changed the fighting scenario into water
The rabbit boss - turning people into carrots
Janemba - opening dimensional doors to hit you from anywhere
```

Probably a lot more